# HorizontalScrollView and Adapter

Tags: android, adapter, horizontalscrollview

Can I use some adapter class with HorizontalScrollView class, similar as I use it with ListView?

Comment: No you can not.Use GallaryView to achieve horizontal scrolling by using adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a horizontal listview, there are many projects on github done by others. You can take a look at them.

[DevsmartLib-Android](https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android)

[Android-Horizontal-ListView](https://github.com/vieux/Android-Horizontal-ListView)

Comment: Thank you. It seems like solution.

Comment: You can also try to use Gallery as a horizontal list view.

Comment: Gallery widget, is deprecated from Android api level 16, that wil raise issue of forward compatibility