# UI Block on creating imageview at runtime

Tags: android, android-launcher

I want to create 600 imageview at runtime and add it to linear layout at runtime.It cause block my user interface. My activity appear when all imageview created and added to linear layout. How to resolve this.

Please help for this.

```
       for(int index = 0; index < ProductItemArray.Image_URL.length; index++)
        {
            ImageView bottomImageView = new ImageView(context);
            bottomImageView.setTag(index);

            if(Helper.isTablet(context))
                bottomImageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(VirtualMirrorActivity.convertDpToPixel(100, context), VirtualMirrorActivity.convertDpToPixel(100, context)));
            else
                bottomImageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(VirtualMirrorActivity.convertDpToPixel(80, context), VirtualMirrorActivity.convertDpToPixel(80, context)));

            UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(bottomImageView, ProductItemArray.Image_URL[index]);
            bottomImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.border);
            linearLayout3.addView(bottomImageView);
            bottomImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
                    linearLayout.removeAllViews();
                    Thread newThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            isAlreadyExistInWishlist = true;
                            URL url_1 = null;
                            try {
                                VMProductListPaging.productUrl = ProductItemArray.Image_small_URL[position];
                                VMProductListPaging.productId = ProductItemArray.productId[position];
                                VMProductListPaging.productName = ProductItemArray.product_Name[position];

                                url_1 = new URL(ProductItemArray.Image_small_URL[position]);
                                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url_1.openConnection().getInputStream());
                                isExecuted = true;
                                bitmapModelsHandler.sendMessage(bitmapModelsHandler.obtainMessage());
                            }
                            catch (Exception e) {
                                //Toast.makeText(context,"Sorry!! This link appears to be broken",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    newThread.start();
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: What does `UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable` do ?

Comment: @fiddler it load image from net.

Comment: 600 `ImageViews` at one moment? If yes this will not works as you're creating to many views.

Comment: you should use lazy load to show images. please refer this [URL](http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/06/android-development-tutorial-asynchronous-lazy-loading-and-caching-of-listview-images/)

Comment: how to add adapter on linear layout

Comment: You can not. You have to use listview, gridview ...

Comment: but i want imageview horizontally which layout should i use

Comment: Look at this post, it is a good tuorial,i think it helps to you . http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-create-simple-android-gallery.html

Comment: @talhakosen I think Gallery is not supported anymore

Comment: @fiddler Really, if it is, what we will use instead of gallery ?

Comment: They say "This widget is no longer supported. Other horizontally scrolling widgets include HorizontalScrollView and ViewPager from the support library." [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html)

Comment: I see, thanks for your information, because of your info i give you 40 rep bounty :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having 600 images in memory in the same time is probably not a good idea.

You should consider using some lazy loading via an adapter (with a ListView, a Gallery, a GridView, a Spinner,etc...) which will manage recycling/releasing of views.

Comment: Spinner is like a dropdown list. ListView might be better suited for your case, no?

Comment: i want these imageview in horizontal which one is best

Comment: Then you might want to use a HorizontalScrollView

Comment: i am using like this   
      <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_below="@+id/sendPhoto"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
  
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
   </HorizontalScrollView>

Comment: and add imageview in linearlayout at runtime

Comment: how can i add adapter on horizontal scrollview

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763821/horizontalscrollview-and-adapter

Comment: but in gallery i have a problem on click on imageview it places in center that is problem in that how to resolve this